# How to restrict the use of storage chests by distance?

Tags: factorio

I want to use deconstruction planner to remove a large forest with my construction robots. The area is really far. I linked it with electricity and roboports.

Now I'm hesitating to put storage chests because I only want them for raw wood stack from deconstruction. I absolutely want to avoid robots to stack other resources from my main base in these chests.

Can I restrict the use of storage chests (yellow ones) by distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can restrict what goes into it by pre-filling the slots with 1 wood each.

Unfortunately if the wood is later removed it might be replaced by something else, so make sure you have enough yellow-chests in the base.  If robots need to put an item into an empty space, they'll go to the nearest yellow chest with an empty slot.